# Converting 24bit RGB image to 8bit grayscale with opencv-node in node.js

Tags: node.js, opencv, webcam, rgb, grayscale

I'm trying to capture images within node.js from a webcam connected to a Raspberry Pi. Capturing works fine, but now when I want to transmit the images I have some serious problems with framerate and lags.

Now my first idea was to convert the RGB images to 8bit grayscale, that should increase the performance by factor 3 (i hope..).

I'm using node.js and opencv-node for this. Here you can see some code snippet for the moment:

```
var startT = new Date().getTime();
var capture = new cv.VideoCapture();
var frame = new cv.Mat;
var grey = new cv.Mat;
var imgPath = __dirname + "/ramdisk/";
var frame_number = 0;

capture.open(0);

if (!capture.isOpened())
{
    console.log("aCapLive could not open capture!");
    return;
}

function ImgCap()
{
    var elapsed = (new Date().getTime() - startT) / 1000;

    capture.read(frame);
    cv.imwrite(imgPath+".bmp", frame);

    id = setImmediate(ImgCap);
}

ImgCap();
```

I tried to use something like

```
cv.cvtColor(frame, grey, "CV_BGR2GRAY");
```

after reading the image but i only get some TypeError saying that argument 2 has to be an integer... I dont know what to do at the moment. I referred to http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html#explanation for converting a rgb to a grayscale image.

Beside I'm still not sure if this just gives mit a 24bit grayscale image instead of 8bit..?!

Thanks for any help in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use CV_BGR2GRAY instead of "CV_BGR2GRAY".

the former is an integral constant, the latter a char*

and, no fear, that will be 8bit grayscale.

Comment: Hello berak, thx for your answer. If I remove the "" I get a ReferenceError: CV_BGR2GRAY is not defined :(

Comment: [the numerical value is 6](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp#L226)   ;)

Comment: Wow, thats what I was searching for! Thank you very very much! :) Network Traffic got significantly reduced and I can produce a bunch more FPS :)

Comment: out of curiosity, how are you transmitting the  images from your pi ? build a mjpg server or such ?

Comment: The RasPi runs a nodejs Server where the communication goes over a Websocket. In Nodejs I'm accessing the Webcam via OpenCV (opencv-node module). I send a message from the client to the server that requires a new frame. The server sends me the frame and when the client received it the next frame is required (so it runs with a kind of handshake). The server should have as few load as possible so I send BMP-frames instead of JPEG. At the moment i get only a poor framerate, so I'm looking how I can tweak the performance a bit. Sorry for my english, i hope it is clear ;)

Comment: "Sorry for my english"  - no problem, perfectly understood our answer - have a look at imdencode()/imdecode() that will be able to compress to jpg/png ( heavy on the pi, but light on the networking )

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will take a look into this function. I'm still looking for a way to stream the images over the websocket so I have a kind of video that can be drawn into a HMTL5 Canvas element. I'm still not sure if the way I'm capturing images from my webcam and transmitting them frame by frame is the best or what possibilities there are left for getting a kind of video from my cam...

Comment: mjpg (what most ip-cams use) seems to be quite natural for this. and it's just html interleaved with single jpgs, easy to implement.

Comment: Hm, I should mention that I'm just using an USB-Webcam that is connected to the RasPi. Well, capturing images like I do works fine, but it gives me the problem, that then a sent image needs too much time to be received by the client, the client wont request the next image in the meantime. In slow networks this causes some very annoying lags, so that I'm waiting up to 20s for the next image, because the one before still has not been received, though it has been sent correct.